# Update SQLite column with text of maximum length from same row

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have an (Android) SQLite table with two columns, `Col1` and `Col2`, containing text. I want to update `Col1` to contain the text with the maximum length out of `Col1` and `Col2` from the same row. I already have a working query but that query takes pretty long to execute on a large data set.

Example data:

```
| Col1 | Col2 | ...
---------------
| AB   | A    |
| A    | ABC  |
| AB   | ABCD |
```

Expected update result:

```
| Col1 | ...
--------
| AB   |
| ABC  |
| ABCD |
```

Working (but slow and hard to read) query:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET Col1 = (
    SELECT Col2
    FROM table AS innerTable
    WHERE table.ROWID = innerTable.ROWID)
WHERE length(Col1) < length(Col2)
```

I am basically looking for something like this, without nested queries:

```sql
UPDATE table SET Col1 = maxLengthString(Col1, Col2)
```

Is there any existing function I have overlooked? Note that this is SQLite, so I can not use `CREATE FUNCTION`.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is as simple as that:

```
update tablename
set col1 = col2
where length(col2) > length(col1);
```

Only the rows where the length of `col1` is less than the length of `col2` will be updated.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p1puP8ue5QErTyacdVdUtA/0).
Results:

```
| Col1 | Col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| AB   | A    |
| ABC  | ABC  |
| ABCD | ABCD |
```

Comment: Oh... I missed the forest for the trees. Thought about that for like 2 hours. Thanks a lot!